# Woocommerce Wordpress Categories>subcategories>products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Problem:

- Shows the category page -> straight to products

Need it so it would show:

- Category page -> Sub Category -> Products

So far I've searched the internet, did not found anything, except one bit, that looks a bit to complicated for my WordPress knowledge.

Comment: just can changed using woocommerce settings. go to `Products -> Categories` choose the category, which you want to show only subcategories( without products ) and select `Edit`. you'll see selectbox `Display type`: choose `Subcategories` and save. your category will show only subgategories

Comment: I did so, still same thing, it just skips the sub category part, so they become useless.